# Question regarding power circuit analysis and current circuit analysis

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, current-source

[image]

I was doing some practice papers for an upcoming test and I was stuck on these particular questions.

First question I was unsure, but for the second question, I have noticed that the ideal wire connecting R1 and R2 creates its own vacuum of parallel circuit. Therefore, from the current divider rule, it doesn't need to account for what happens in R3 and the switch itself. So I believe Q11 is option B.

Any advice on how to approach these two questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: are you able to simplify the second circuit by reducing series or parallel resistors into one? You can add a schematic **using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar**. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Well, if R1 was infinity.....

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve both of these problems yourself. Show us **all** of your work, then ask a **specific** question. In this case you need to fully explain what you mean by "creates its own vacuum of parallel circuit". Clarify what "it" refers to in the sentence after that.